# calculating big numbers in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, double

i want to calculate x in this formula :

> r=g^x mod n = B

and variables are :

> ```
>     Dim g As Double
>     Dim x As Double
>     Dim n As Double
>     Dim b As Double
>     Dim m As Double
>     Dim r As Double
>     x = 1
>     b = 9789467
>     g = 10895499
>     n = 16777216
>     m = 1
> ```

and here my codes :

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 16777215

    m = i
    r = (g ^ m) Mod n

    If r = b Then
        MsgBox("result = " + i)
    End If
Next

MsgBox("not found")
```

but , it's just works on small numbers 
and with my numbers... not working :(
i would appreciate any solution guys :)
and even if u got the x value from any other languages ... it's fine :)
thank you :)

Comment: If it's just about getting the value of `x` regardless of any language you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10895499+%5E+x+mod+16777216+%3D+9789467) for that kind of stuff

Comment: thank you @Sehnsucht ... it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Numerics and use BigInteger